# Zabbix text value trigger

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to configure a Zabbix trigger for an external check which has to react if the value returned by the external check is different from :

```
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes

Replication running

Connection to host.com closed.
```

Using `{db2.playtech.ru.com:mysql_replica_check.sh.last(60)}<>expression` throws syntax error.

Is there a way to configure this trigger in Zabbix?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `str()` [trigger function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) would be the best choice:

```
{db2.playtech.ru.com:mysql_replica_check.sh.str(string)}=0
```